# Making recursive async requests using the Play! WSClient

Tags: asynchronous, recursion, playframework, ws-client

I would appreciate any hints on how to make recursive requests with the WSClient. I am accessing a REST api which returns nodes of a tree in json format, for example this would be the root node:

```
{
  id: "root"
  children:[
    {
      id: "node1"
      children:[...]
    },
    {
      id: "node2"
      children:[...]
    },
    {
      id: "node3"
      children:[...]
    }
  ]
}
```

To access each node the url pattern is

```
root/node1/node1-1
```

What i would like to do is to traverse the whole tree and get some information according to some criteria.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `flatMap` is the way to go. On a more serious note, you should show what you have tried and where you got stuck rather than expect somebody to come up with the solution for you.

Comment: Hello, i am not asking for someone to give me the solution This is the reason i'm not giving any extra details. So far i can access a single node using the CompletionStage from java8.

Answer (score 0):

This task is like a twin of classic directory tree traverse.

I am pretty sure you can do this with clean recursion, but using Akka is a more clean way to do it.

Here are the examples:

[Use akka actors to traverse directory tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935180/use-akka-actors-to-traverse-directory-tree)

https://gist.github.com/TheDIM47/8bfa2bbf80e791c00e73

You can use Java as well, but it's a more verbose.